# Co-ordinating class contracts in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

The core of my application is an engine which takes a problem specification, encoded as a data structure, and generates the results we need. There are two ways to instantiate the spec data structure: by parsing a script or through a Rails UI. In the Rails case, the data structure is the model objects in the DB, in the script case it's an in-memory instance of a model class. The engine is in a separate gem, so that the script-driven process can be run standalone without needing Rails around.

My question is how to ensure that the two data-structures, the Rails DB model and the in-memory model, fulfill the same contract. If this was Java, I would write an interface that both model classes would implement, but in Ruby I'm relying on duck-typing. I will have tests for each model, but it would be more DRY to have just one test suite. I can't see how to share the tests, however, between the gem project and the rails project.

The key challenge is: suppose I add a responsibility to the Rails model, how do I guarantee that the corresponding responsibility gets added to the script memory model, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should create a module whose responsibility would be to check that the receiver class contains the demanded methods.

Something like this:

```
module Contract
  STATIC_METHODS   = [ :class_foo ]
  INSTANCE_METHODS = [ :instance_foo ]

  def self.included(receiver)
    STATIC_METHODS.each do |method|
      raise("missing class method #{method}") unless receiver.respond_to? method
    end
    INSTANCE_METHODS.each do |method|
      raise("missing instance method #{method}") unless receiver.instance_methods.include? method.to_s
    end
  end
end

class YourClass
  def self.class_foo
  end

  def instance_foo

  end

  include Contract
end
```

Beware to include the `Contract` at the end of your file otherwise, it will logically fail (methods won't be defined).

Regarding your tests, you should create some common tests and run them in your classes with something like: `it_should_behave_like`

Comment: Thanks. On a purely practical level, where would you put this module so that it can be used in both projects? It's test code, so it would seem odd (to me) to have it in its own gem. However, I'm not sure what other mechanisms Ruby provides for including remote code (i.e. not local to the containing project).

Comment: a clean way would be to develop some sbmodule: http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html. Otherwise, put the file wherever you want and provide and require it with an absolute path.